# calling back-end api (laravel) from getServerSideProps() in next js

Tags: laravel, next.js

I am using `next js` as a front-end and `laravel` as a back-end. and i want to call back-end (laravel) api from getServerSideProps() method. as shown below

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const response = await Axios.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/event',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        Cookie: context.req.headers.cookie,
    },
})
const events = response.events
console.log(response)
return {
    props: { events },
}
}
```

so i have also set the cookie but i am getting response with message unauthenticated like below
[image]

Comment: Does that cookie have the expected/valid value? Is the same request successful if your try in Postman?

Comment: I've been stuck at this for days now. It looks like the only option is to make the request on the client using useEffect. For me, I wanted to check if user was authenticated and to redirect the user to the appropriate. I figured to avoid flashing content, it would be best to do this check server side, but looks like I have to show a preloader whilst I run the check using a hook.

Comment: Any luck about this? I have the same problem and nobody cares at all...

Comment: export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const response = await Axios.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/event',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        ...context.req.headers
    },
})
const events = response.events
console.log(response)
return {
    props: { events },
}
} 

@O

Comment: headers : {  ...context.req.headers }. you have to destruct context.req.headers and then assign to headers.it solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to say a huge THANK YOU to [Riaz Kahn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9510957/riaz-khan) for his answer.  After a lot of banging my face against a wall this was the answer.  I'm going to post a working example of my getServerSideProps function for anyone arriving here in the future.  The `getUser({[configObject]})` function is just returning a promise from an `axios.get('my-user/route', config)` call.  This is working properly in a Next 13 app using standard pages functionality (not using experimental app directory).

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: any) => {
    const {req, res} = context;

    try {
        const {data: user} = await getUser({
            headers: {...req.headers}
        });

        return {
            props: {
                fallback: {user}
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.writeHead(302, {Location: '/login'});
        res.end();
    }
}
```